# Prove that if $X_2$ has a uniform distribution then $X_1 \oplus_2 X_2$ too

Tags: number-theory, statistics, cryptography

Assume we have two independent random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ with values in the set $Z_2 = {0,1}$. Prove that if $X_2$ has a uniform distribution then $X_1 \oplus_2 X_2$ has also the uniform distribution. (Used in "coin tossing by phone").

I know from a theorem that this is true and that the uniform probability distribution will be $P(y=0)=1/2$ and $P(y=0)=1/2$. But I don't know how to prove it. Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Pr(X_1=0)$ be $p$, so $\Pr(X_1=1)=1-p$.

The event  $X_1\oplus X_2=0$ can occur in two possible disjoint  ways: (i) $X_1=0$ and $X_2=0$ or (ii) $X_1=1$ and $X_2=1$.

The probability of (i) is $(p)(1/2)$, and the probability of (ii) is $(1-p)(1/2)$.

If we add them, we get:
$$\Pr(X_1\oplus X_2=0)=(p)(1/2)+(1-p)(1/2)=1/2.$$

Since the only possible values of $X_1\oplus X_2$ are $0$ and $1$, it follows that $\Pr(X_1\oplus X_2)=1/2$.

Comment: You are welcome.